# Mathematical proof of rate of return after tax

Tags: taxes, rate-of-return

It is well known in engineering economic that rate of return after tax can be computed by multiplying tax rate and nomial rate of return which is the rate of return before tax.
This relation is known to be accurate when decay is not included in our analysis. 
Actually it makes calculation much easier than comptung IRR  after tax. 
I need to make sure this relation is mathematically correct but never found a mathematical proof to it.
Please draw a mathematical proof for

```
RoR_AT=(1-taxrate).RoR_BT
```

- RoR_AT: rate of return after tax
- RoR_BT: rate of return before tax
- Taxrate: Tax rate

The RoR is defined by the interest rate that make the NPV=0  computed after or before tax.

A reference to the  formula RoR_AT=(1-taxrate).RoR_BT is

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/after-tax-real-rate-of-return.asp

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simplification. If you make `r` before tax, then pay `t%` tax on `r`, then your net return after tax is

```
r - t*r = (1-t)r
```

Note that `t` in the formula is in decimal form, meaning if the tax rate is 30%, then `t` will be `0.30`.

Comment: did you assume RoR_AT=r - t*r ? how does it obtained?

Comment: Say you earn a return `R`. You must pay tax on that return at some rate, `T`. The amount of tax you pay is therefore `T` times `R`. So the net return after tax is paid is `R` minus `T*R`.

Comment: Rete ofcreturn is not like that, it is rate that whoch npw=0. The taxable income should be first computed in cashflow and then tax be applied each year.

Comment: @behradmahboobi That's how _IRR_ is calculated by using _after tax_ cash flows. The tax must be computed for each period _before_ calculating the actual rate of return. The formula you mention can be used an _approximation_ that is not accurate in some situations (like for a depreciating asset). See an example [here](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/static/companion.websites/9780195161526/interactive/IT/ITE.htm)

Comment: In other words, the formula you mention can be used to compute the after-tax return for _each period_, which is then used to compute IRR, but it is not always appropriate to apply to a before-tax IRR to get an _after-tax_ IRR.

Comment: Depreciation in tax calculation make that formula incorrect, so you can assume theres no depreciation in cashflow and prove it.

Comment: In literature such as the website i have posted in the question, the formula is claimed to be accurate without depreciation. Please read investopedia website link in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, p = principal, r = dividend rate, d = dividend, t = tax rate, a = after tax dividend, and y = after tax dividend yield:

p * r = d

d - (d * t) = a

a / p = y

Then working with

r - (r * t) = y

show that

r - (r * t) = a / p

as

(p * r) - (p * r * t) = a

and

(p * r) - (p * r * t) = d - (d * t)

and proven with

p * r = d .

Comment: Rate of return is the interest rate at which npw=0. The above proof is not true.

Comment: r - (r * t) = a / p was proven to be true. Here 'p' represents a principal value and 'a' represents an after-tax dividend. Then 'r' represents a dividend rate while 't' represents a tax rate.

Comment: The first formula p.r=d is incorrect for ROR

Comment: One should solve npw(r)=0 to obtain ROR

Comment: What was posted could be represented in an example as [.04 = (1 - .20)  * .05] and that is a simplified version of [.04 = .05 - (.05  * .20)] .

Comment: The example in reference is an example to show how the the formula works, however it does prove it in any way.

Comment: Mahboobi shouldn't make broad symbolic declarations and then say prove-it. No one knows what they are trying to prove. I proved one aspect of the calculation that I thought was being referred-to. That aspect could actually be proved as "associative property of multiplication". But I thought the associative property was deeply enough involved to be interesting as a proof that compares two different calculation techniques.

Comment: It is not obvious how p.r=d came from in your prove, how can i be sure its true? Symbol r stand for IRR  here.